# How to set UIBackgroundConfiguration for UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, mac-catalyst

I am struggling to change background properties of UIButton.
They can be easily modified using "Background Configuration" settings in Interface Builder:

[image: screenshot]

but I don't understand how to set them programmatically.

For example, I try to do it like this:

```
UIBackgroundConfiguration * config = [UIBackgroundConfiguration listPlainCellConfiguration];
[config setStrokeColor: UIColor.labelColor];
```

but where should I assign this 'config' value? There is nothing like 'button.backgroundConfiguration' property or anything similar for UIButton object.

Note:
'configuration' property of UIButton object is not available in code (Objective C, Mac Catalyst, iOS 15) despite documentation statement, screenshot attached. Will be great to know the reason why this is so.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can set background image for `UIButton` using `setBackgroundImage:for:`.

Answer (score 3):

The background configuration is part of the UIButtonConfiguration (the button's `configuration`).

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibuttonconfiguration/3750780-background?language=objc

Here's an example of configuring a button created in the storyboard:

```
UIButtonConfiguration * con = self.button.configuration;
[con setTitle: @"Hello"];
UIBackgroundConfiguration * back = con.background;
[back setStrokeColor: UIColor.labelColor];
[back setStrokeWidth: 3];
[back setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
self.button.configuration = con;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Please read the question. I am asking about UIBackgroundConfiguration (iOS 14.0+), not about UIButtonConfiguration (iOS 15.0).

Comment: Please read the answer. The button configuration has a background property to which you assign your UIBackgroundConfiguration. Click the link.

Comment: Please provide a working code example (Objective C) of assigning UIBackgroundConfiguration to UIButton.

Comment: My answer is correct and answers exactly what you asked. You want to know, to what property, in code, does the Xcode 13 Interface Builder button background configuration stuff correspond? I have told you.

Comment: UIButton has no 'configuration' property, at least in Objective C code for Mac Catalyst app. Links to documentation does not help this property to appear, sorry.

Comment: Yes it does. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/3750768-configuration?language=objc That is a UIButtonConfiguration, and a UIButtonConfiguration has a `background` property that is a UIBackgroundConfiguration. Which is where we started.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238117/discussion-between-kibernetik-and-matt).

Comment: Added some actual code. I've no idea why you claim this doesn't work.

Comment: Your code is not valid for Mac Catalyst.

Answer (score -1):

It happens that 'button.configuration.background' property is not available in the Xcode 13 beta 5 for Mac Catalyst.

One have to wait for newer Xcode release to get this feature working from code.

Comment: Just For note. xcode 13 is no longer in beta. Xcode 13 GM has been available for a month.

Comment: Yes, but its Mac Catalyst supports macOS 11.3 only. And macOS 12.0 support is required for Mac Catalyst 15.0 to operate.